# Make Realm Loop Generic and Reusable in Swift

Tags: swift, class, generics, realm

*Swift 4, Xcode 9.2*

Here are a few Realm classes I have:

```
class Dog: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var updated = Date()
  //Other properties...
}

class Cat: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var updated = Date()
  //Other properties...
}

class Horse: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var updated = Date()
  //Other properties...
}
```

Let's say I have some code like this where I compare two realms and create an object with a specific `Dog` class:

```
let remoteDogs = remoteRealm.objects(Dog.self)

for remoteDog in remoteDogs{
  if let localDog = realm.objects(Dog.self).filter("id = %@",remoteDog.id).first{
    // Update
    if localDog.updated < remoteDog.updated{
      //Remote is newer; replace local with it
      realm.create(Dog.self, value: remoteDog, update:true)
    }
  }
}
```

This works great, but I need to do this same stuff on a whole bunch of Realm classes that I have. So I'm trying to make it more generic like this:

```
let animals = [Dog.self, Cat.self, Horse.self]

for animal in animals{
  let remoteAnimals = remoteRealm.objects(animal)

  for remoteAnimal in remoteAnimals{
    if let localAnimal = realm.objects(animal).filter("id = %@",remoteAnimal.id).first{
      // Update
      if localAnimal.updated < remoteAnimal.updated{
        //Remote is newer; replace local with it
        realm.create(animal, value: remoteAnimal, update:true)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This sort of works, but anytime I want to reference the property of an object (like with `remoteAnimal.id` and `remoteAnimal.updated`) then the compiler complains because it doesn't know what kind of object a `remoteAnimal` is.

Has anyone done something like this before? Any ideas how I can do this so that I don't have to write this same code over and over for each of my Realm classes? Thanks!

Comment: The problem here is that `realm.objects(T.self)` returns a `Results<T>` and the type of `animals` is `[Object.Type]`.  This is because the nearest common parent for all elements of `animals` is `Object`.  Josh's answer is dead on: if all three objects inherit from `Animal`, `animals` will have a type `[Animal.Type]` and the compiler should correctly give you back an animal for `localAnimal`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Realm Object does not have **id** or **updated**.  You can have your Dog, 
Cat and Horse classes inherit from an Animal class that is a subclass of Object and that does have **id** or **updated**. Since these properties are defined on Animal they will be usable in all of the subclasses (Dog, Cat, Horse).

```
class Animal: Object {
  @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
  @objc dynamic var updated = Date()
  //Other properties...
}

class Dog: Animal {
  //Other properties...
}
```

**EDIT** you can also abuse Objective C's [NSObject setValue:forKey:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1415969-setvalue) to set the property by name.  This is very sloppy typing and not good object oriented design but it does work.  Here is a playground:

```
import UIKit

class A: NSObject {
  @objc var customProperty = 0
}
let a = A()
a.setValue(5, forKey: "customProperty")
print(a.customProperty)
```

Comment: I just added my class definitions.